# focus the cursor on the column which i select to edit

Tags: vb.net

i am using the grid from dev express.. in vb.net 2005..

```
when i choose a row to edit, in that row, when i select a particular column , then cursor show focus in that particular column , instead it is focused in the first column in that select row..  

I want to focus the cursor on the column which i select to edit..for the particular row..
```

advance thanks...

Comment: Can you please reformat your question so it is readable?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the DevExpress online support is excellent (and free). Not sure if it's a valid way to answer a question on this site to point you in the direction of another, but anyway...try starting here: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/